# Save on change of CommandStack

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

probably a really easy newbie question but I can't manage to get it for already a pair of days, so I'll aks it here. My scope: I have an RCP application with some Graphical Editors (extensions of EditorPart). In my editor I want to catch any changes and save them directly. For that I catch the moment in which my CommandStack gets changed and start a doSave method. The problem is that my save method calls a CommadStack change event and if i skip this call than my changes are saved but my editor has still got a dirty flag. My wished behaviour would be that the dirty flag is away(like a normal save behaviour).
Both my CommandStack change and my doSave method are below. Could you please help me?

```
@Override
public void commandStackChanged(EventObject event) {
    firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY);
    doSave(null);
    setDirty(false);
}


public void doSave(final IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) {

        editorSaving = true;
        SafeRunner.run(new SafeRunnable() {

            public void run() throws Exception {
                IFile targetFile = getFile();

                List<GraphicalEditPart> editParts = DiagramUtil.getAllEditParts(NetEditor.this);
                Rectangle offsetBounds = DiagramUtil.getBounds(editParts);

                saveDiagramProperties();
                List<INetTransition> transitionsToExpand = saveSubdiagramGroups();
                FileUtil.saveDiagram(getNetDiagram(), targetFile,
                        NetEditor.this);
                getCommandStack().markSaveLocation();


                for (INetTransition trans : transitionsToExpand) {
                    trans.setExpanded(true);
                }
            }
        });
        setDirty(false);
        editorSaving = false;
    }
```

With getCommandStack().markSaveLocation() I call once more the commandStackChanged and get in a loop. How can I solve this problem? Without it my editor remains dirty after save.

Thanks and Greets,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

How about adding IPropertyListener to your Editor and listen for IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY. For the listener implementation perform save if editor is dirty otherwise do nothing.